# Eliminating a variable from two expressions

Tags: equation-solving, parametric-functions

I have the following equations -

```
T = (2*cos[α]*sin[β])/sin[α + β];

sin[α]/sin[β] = sqrt[1 - V/E];
```

And I want to eliminate `β` from the two equations so as to obtain an expression for T. How should I proceed?

Comment: Never use upper-case letters (T, V, E, ...) to start the names of variables as these may conflict with internal names in *Mathematica*.  `Sin` is the proper usage, not `sin`, `Sqrt` not `sqrt`, ... etc.

Comment: Thanks David, I am new to this software.

Comment: Also note all built in functions all start with caps (`Sin,Sqrt, etc).  You can `Solve` the second expression for beta and sub into the first.

Answer (score 3):

Or can just use eliminate.  First get into equation form without the upper case variables.  E is a particularly bad idea unless you mean the built in constant E.

```
eq1 = t == (2*Cos[α]*Sin[β])/Sin[α + β]//TrigExpand;
eq2 = Sin[α]/Sin[β] == Sqrt[1 - v/e];

Eliminate[{eq1, eq2}, β] // Simplify
(*t^2*v == 4*e*(t - 1)*Cos[α]^2*)
```

Comment: you can finish this out with a `Solve[..,t]` (+)

Answer (score 1):

```
Solve[Sin[α]/Sin[β] = Sqrt[1 - V/E], β]
```

(*

```
π - ArcSin[(Sqrt[E] Sin[α])/Sqrt[E - V]]
```

*)

```
T /. β -> π - ArcSin[(Sqrt[E] Sin[α])/Sqrt[E - V]]
```

$-\frac{2 \sqrt{e} \sin (\alpha ) \cos (\alpha ) \csc \left(\alpha -\sin
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{e} \sin (\alpha )}{\sqrt{e-V}}\right)\right)}{\sqrt{e-V}}$

Answer (score 1):

note the result here simplifies nicely using `TrigExpand`

```
(2*Cos[α]*Sin[β])/Sin[α + β] /. 
   Solve[Sin[α]/Sin[β] == Sqrt[1 - v/e] , β] // 
  Simplify
```

> (*  conditional expression *)

```
result = Simplify[%, Assumptions -> C[1] ∈ Integers] // 
   TrigExpand // Simplify
```

[image]

and simpler still if you add `Assumptions -> 0 < v < e`  (if true of course)

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[result /. {v -> .1, e -> .2}], {α, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What does this mean C[1] \[Element] Integers ?

Comment: the first conditional expression is in terms of unspecified integer constants ( due to the inverse trig function).  When you insert that back into the expression for `t` those constants simplify out (due to the forward trig functions).  Unfortunately we are left with a `ConditionalExpression` that still says `C[1]` must be an integer even though there is no `C[1]` in the expression, so my last simplify just gets rid of that.

Comment: My assumptions expression doesn't work and I get this - https://imgur.com/jgWCW75

Comment: looks like you have a letter `o` instead of zero in there.